# CS0103 when viewing value of local variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Viewing a local variable returns **CS0103**:

[image]

I'm using VS2015 Update 2 and this is a DNX project.

Have I set up my project wrong?  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you compile in Release mode or in Debug mode?

Comment: My though process was the same - I'm in Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that **Use Compatibility Mode** resolves this problem.  [A bug *was* raised](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable) but appears to have been dismissed.

[image]